# Writing tests for a Laravel package

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create my first package for Laravel. I created the folder `packages/<vendor>/<package_name>/src`, prescribed it in composer.json and added a service provider configuration. The problem arose when writing tests. One of the tests I use Illuminate\Http\Response, which is absent in the vendor folder of my package. When I install the framework into the package folder it works, but to install Laravel inside Laravel it seems to me not quite correct. Is there another option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `composer.json`, you can add a 'require-dev' section, which adds requirements that are only included on development builds:

```
"require-dev": {
    "illuminate/http": "*"
}
```

You should also look into using ["orchestra/testbench"](https://github.com/orchestral/testbench) for mocking up a laravel application for testing a stand-alone package. It allows you to configure a fake Laravel environment (set the app config, run migrations on an in-memory SQLite instance, etc.) for testing.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!